# ValueError: Unable to coerce list of <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Series/DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-structures, biopython

I am using distance_df function from biopandas to calculate distance of a bunch of atoms form a reference point. The function is working fine, but I am getting this Value error in one part of my code. Basically I am dividing the CLR into 4 parts to check distance of each part from the interacting amino acids. Everything is working fine, but the code is stuck at the last line, it was working before a month, was there any update to biopandas? It's more biology so if anyone has any question about the code i would be happy to clear them. I haven't encountered this error ever and have no idea what to do. Thank you in advance :)

```
split_clr = []
path = "/media/New Volume/2RH1.pdb"
ppdb = PandasPdb().read_pdb(path)
atom_df = ppdb.df['ATOM']
hetatm = ppdb.df['HETATM'][(ppdb.df['HETATM']['residue_name']=="CLR")]
chains = np.unique(hetatm.chain_id)
residues = np.unique(hetatm.residue_number)
for chain in chains:    
    for res in range(len(residues)):
        data = hetatm[(hetatm['residue_number']==residues[res])&(hetatm['chain_id']==chain)]
        if len(data) !=0:
            split_clr.append(data)
for nu in range(len(split_clr)):
    upper = []
    middle1 = []
    middle2 = []
    lower = []
        
    # upper part of CLR
    clr_o = split_clr[nu][split_clr[nu]['atom_name']=='O1']
    x_o = clr_o.x_coord
    y_o = clr_o.y_coord
    z_o = clr_o.z_coord
    reference_point=x_o,y_o,z_o
    dista = ppdb.distance_df(atom_df, xyz=reference_point)
```

snapshot of the error:
[image: Error snapshot]

Comment: I would be happy to provide any explanation to any of the lines in the code. If you are familiar with the above-mentioned pandas error please help me figure it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, everyone. I have solved the issue. If anyone gets similar error here is the solution:
In my case the error was because these three variables:

```
x_o = clr_o.x_coord
y_o = clr_o.y_coord
z_o = clr_o.z_coord
```

are returning a pandas series, which includes the index number and the value. Now, when I am calling distance_df function of biopandas, it takes xyz coordinates as a list, but I was passing a pandas series. Simplest way that I found in my case is to add float which gives just a single output, like this:

```
x_o = float(clr_o.x_coord)
y_o = float(clr_o.y_coord)
z_o = float(clr_o.z_coord)
```

Thank you

Comment: cool ! just accept your own answer flagging the V shaped tag under the answer. Didnt know biopandas even existed here the link for the others interested http://rasbt.github.io/biopandas/